# date validation in tapestry server side

Tags: java, tapestry

Im trying to put some validation in the date field. The condition is the effective date field should be less or equal to the current date and it should be 1st of month.

Im doing it in tapestry.The data type is DATE. im using tapestry as yo know you will have .html page a, .java file and .page file. Im doing it in the java file . So please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the form is submitted t5 emits various events during the different stages. On EventConstants.VALIDATE is a good place to perform more complex validations that are not supported by t5 out of the box, or to perform cross-field validation serverside.

```
    @Component
    private Form myForm;
    ...
    @OnEvent(value = EventConstants.VALIDATE, component = "myForm")
    public void onCreateEditValidate() {
       // do validation and if any error record it
       myForm.record(theDateField, "Dang, try again!");
       ...
```

http://tapestry.apache.org/forms-and-validation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onValidate event too as stated at the end of the link jon martin solas posted.
Something like:

```
void onValidateFromYouDateFieldId(..) throws ValidationException{
   //your custom validations
}
```

you can check out this example for more information:

http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/input/morevalidation

http://tapestry.apache.org/forms-and-validation.html#FormsandValidation-OverridingtheTranslatorwithEvents